# Keep Covariance Matrix symmetric and positive definite while updating

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance, least-squares, positive-definite, recursive-algorithms

I am working on a Recursive least square estimate problem and realised that covariance matrix is not symmetric and positive definite after few iterations. How to ensure covariance matrix to be positive definite during update ? I tried reading few publications but unfortunately its above my skill set. I am not looking for a very optimised and computationally effective solution but some thing that is quick enough to test RLS algorithm while keeping covariance matrix positive definite.

Thanks

Comment: what does the update step look like?

Comment: @user619894 This is the Recursive Least square algorithm - Forgetting factor https://se.mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/algorithms-for-online-estimation.html#buagqes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use Potter's Square Root Algorithm. Various implementations can be found in [chapter 7](http://bcs.wiley.com/he-bcs/Books?action=resource&bcsId=9264&itemId=1118851218&resourceId=36845),  Grewal, Andrews:Kalman Filtering: Theory and Practice with MATLAB